# Is C# Isolated model a thing with console apps?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions, .net-8.0

With .NET8 finally becoming the new standard for Azure Functions I learned that there is also this newer thing called "isolated worker model" that is going to replace the old "in process model". This requires some code tweaking to already existing function apps that run in Azure (code and library updates mainly).

I have been using dependency injection and similar coding logic also in my .NET console apps. This might be a dumb question, but I was wondering does this worker model change affect also other solutions than function apps? For example if I want to move from .NET6 to .NET8 in my console apps I guess I need to just raise .NET version and update libraries accordingly. Worker model change is only a thing in Azure functions, or am I missing something?

Comment: *"Worker model change is only a thing in Azure functions [...]?"* - Correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you and ***@madreflection*** mentioned, the worker model change applies only for Azure Functions and is not relevant to console apps as they are standalone processes on a host machine and not managed within a serverless environment like Azure Functions.

- This change is to manage Azure Functions execution within the Azure platform, particularly with regards to how the runtime environment is managed and how functions interact with external dependencies.

The isolated worker model in Azure Functions allows your project to target .NET versions of other runtime components independently.

This model provides few other advantages:

- Prevents conflicts between assemblies used in the app with the versions of the same assemblies used by the host process.
- Provides flexibility and control to manage the function configurations.

When upgrading .NET console apps to .NET 8, you just have to update the project's target framework and the packages to latest versions compatible with .NET 8.

- **Packages of Isolated Azure function:**
- Below are the packages which supports Isolated Worker model in Azure Functions.

**pom.xml:**

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.20.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore" Version="1.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.16.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

**References:**

1. [C# Azure Functions in an isolated worker process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide?tabs=windows)
2. [Migrate .NET function apps from the in-process model to the isolated worker model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/migrate-dotnet-to-isolated-model?tabs=net8)